# Automapper configuration

Tags: c#, automapper

Is it enought to call Mapper.Initialize in Application_Start() in global.asax or should some IoC container take care of the lifetime scoping ?

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
     Mapper.Initialize(x=>x.AddProfile(new SomeProfile()));
}
```

Comment: AutoMapper runs very singleton-ish

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be enough.  I've never had a problem with initializing Automapper this way.