# EF Code First and IIS recycling

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, iis, automapper

We are experiencing errors in our website. I checked the event viewer and when an app pool recycle was executed problems in EF code first start rising (note that this does not happen every time, app pool recycles after every 2 hours and there are instances although not always, that EF code first errors are experienced).

```
        var user = GetSingle(u => u.Id == userId);
        if (user == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("user");

        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<User, SessionUserDetails>();
        var sessionUserDetails = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<User, SessionUserDetails>(user);
```

When mapping happens that's when the error occurs. If there is no user, it will throw an ArgumentNullException. I double checked the User and SessionUserDetails and both have same variables. I don't know where else to look.

Here is the exception of the automapper:

```
 System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 at AutoMapper.ConfigurationStore.<>c__DisplayClass35.  <FindExplicitlyDefinedTypeMap>b__34(TypeMap x)
 at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
 at AutoMapper.ConfigurationStore.FindExplicitlyDefinedTypeMap(Type sourceType, Type destinationType)
 at AutoMapper.ConfigurationStore.CreateTypeMap(Type source, Type destination, String profileName)
 at AutoMapper.ConfigurationStore.CreateMap[TSource,TDestination](String profileName)
 at AutoMapper.ConfigurationStore.CreateMap[TSource,TDestination]()
 at AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap[TSource,TDestination]()
 at MVCAujourdhuiBL.Service.UserReg.UserService.GetUserDetails(Int32 userId)
```

I dont know where else to look. I even forced the iis to recycle but i cannot replicate the error. Any help would be much appreciated. :) Thanks

Comment: At which place did you wrote the AutoMapper code in your App?

Comment: Also can you just check if Mapper is not disposed after app pool recycle perhaps using logging mechanism? If so you my re-initialize that as shown in the post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5537192/automapper-configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the CreateMap call really in your Controller Action? You should pull it out into a app_start module.  It's not thread safe and could be causing your issues.

http://automapper.codeplex.com/workitem/3197

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It was indeed the automapper, i thought it was EF who was causing the problems. Thank you. We are not experiencing such errors anymore.